# Displaying a custom notice on Emails based on item custom field highest value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

On WooCommerce I have a custom field **`days_manufacture`** for each product with different (integer) values.

Also I Have this code that displays a message on cart page with the highest value of **"days of manufacture"**:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'days_of_manufacture');
function days_of_manufacture() {
    $day_txt = ' ' . __('day', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
    $days_txt = ' ' . __('days', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
    $text = __('Your Order will be produced in: ', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
    $max_days = 0;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if($cart_item['days_manufacture'] > $max_days)
            $max_days = $cart_item['days_manufacture'];

    if($max_days != 0) {
        if ($max_days == 1)
            $days_txt = $day_txt;

        $output = $text . $max_days . $days_txt;
        echo "<div class='woocommerce-info'>$output</div>";
    }
}
```

Now I would like to display this message in emails.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, changing a little bit the function of [**this answer to your previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459649/woocommerce-custom-notice-on-in-thankyou-and-my-account-view-order-pages/39459834#39459834) and I additionally hook this function to **`woocommerce_email_before_order_table`** hook for the orders notification emails.

So you will replace that existing function by this one. And you replace also the inserted function in both templates *(see below)*.

This function can handle displaying your custom dynamic message in the templates (as before) and in your email notifications.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'days_of_manufacture_view_order_and_email', 99);
function days_of_manufacture_view_order_and_email($order, $type='email') {
    $day_txt = ' ' . __('day', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
    $days_txt = ' ' . __('days', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
    $max_days = 0;

    // Your customized style for the email template (to adapt for your needs)
    $style = 'border:solid 2px #ededed; padding:10px; font-weight:bold;';

    // Your customized text goes in here
    $text = __('Your Order will be produced in: ', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
        if(get_post_meta($item['product_id'], 'days_manufacture', true) > $max_days )
            $max_days = get_post_meta($item['product_id'], 'days_manufacture', true);

    if($max_days != 0) {
        if ($max_days == 1)
            $days_txt = $day_txt;

        $output = $text . $max_days . $days_txt;

        // displayed on the email notifications
        if($type == 'email')
            echo "<div class='woocommerce-info' style='$style'>$output</div>"; // <== Customize the styles if needed
        // displayed on the woocommerce templates   
        else
            echo "<div class='woocommerce-info' style='display:block !important;'>$output</div>"; // displayed on the templates
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**The templates changes**

Now in both templates within your active child theme (or theme) [**`woocommerce`** templates folder](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/):

- [**`your_theme/woocommerce/myaccount/view-order.php`**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/myaccount/view-order.php)
- [**`your_theme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php`**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/checkout/thankyou.php)

You will change this line:

```
<?php days_of_manufacture_order_view($order); // <== inserted Here ?>
```

By this line:

```
<?php days_of_manufacture_view_and_email($order, 'template'); // <== inserted Here ?>
```

Now the custom notice is displayed on emails too and still works on **`Thankyou` view order** page and on

**`My account > Orders > view order`**` pages too.

---

References:

- [WooCommerce - Custom notice on in Thankyou and “My account” view order pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459649/woocommerce-custom-notice-on-in-thankyou-and-my-account-view-order-pages/39459834#39459834)
- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Woocommerce template myaccount > view-order.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/myaccount/view-order.php)
- [Woocommerce template checkout > thankyou.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/checkout/thankyou.php)