# Display product ACF fields on a specific WooCommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

So I almost got it, but this last detail of specifying WooCommerce emails is leaving my head in a bit of a knot here.

I need to show ACF (advanced custom fields) fields of products (in this case it's a custom shipping time)

- But only in the new order email (processing order and waiting payment order sent to the client) and then new order email to admin.

---

This was the main way I found: ["Display product ACF field value in Woocommerce transaction emails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738555/display-product-acf-field-value-in-woocommerce-transaction-emails) Thank you in advance @[LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)

I also added some conditional settings to it (mind me my PHP is very beginning copy-pasty)
which are working pretty well.

However what I can't get around is making it work only on new order emails.
I have it setup like this, and it works, however it shows on all emails that contain the email order details, and I can't have the shipping time showing on the completed order emails as it will create confusion.

```php
// Display product ACF custom field value shipping in email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    // Targeting email notifications only
    if ( 'new_order' == $email->id )   
        return $item_name;

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();
    $othershipping = get_field( 'shipping_custom', $product->get_id());

    if( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "24h") {
        $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . '<p>Get it tomorrow(24h)</p>' . '</p>';
    }
    elseif( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "2-5 days") {
        $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . '<p>2-5 days</p>' . '</p>';
    }
    elseif( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "other") {
        $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . $othershipping . '</p>';
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

---

I have tried switching the

```php
if ( 'new_order' == $email->id )
```

to

```php
if ( 'new_order' != $email->id )
```

But that just makes it not work anywhere.

---

I also thought it could be this part

```php
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
```

Where I need to add `($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )`

```php
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item, $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email )
```

But it makes the email return an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work with the code below

> Note: my answer is largely based on: ["Customize order item meta only for WooCommerce admin email notifications"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344780/11987538). CREDITS: @[Loictheaztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec) so don't forget to upvote that answer to!

```php
// Setting the "sent_to_admin" as a global variable
function email_order_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    $GLOBALS['email_data'] = array(
        'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, // <== HERE we set "$sent_to_admin" value
        'email_id' => $email->id, // The email ID (to target specific email notification)
    );
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_order_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);

function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) {

        // Getting the custom 'email_data' global variable
        $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
        $email_data = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_data'];

        // Only for new order
        if( is_array( $email_data ) && $email_data['email_id'] == 'new_order' ) {

            // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
            $product = $item->get_product();

            $othershipping = get_field( 'shipping_custom', $product->get_id());

            if( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "24h") {
                $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
                <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . '<p>Get it tomorrow(24h)</p>' . '</p>';
            }
            elseif( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "2-5 days") {
                $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
                <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . '<p>2-5 days</p>' . '</p>';
            }
            elseif( $shpng_value = get_field('shipping_', $product->get_id())== "other") {
                $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shpng" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
                <strong>' . __( 'Shipping time', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . $othershipping . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $item_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
```